# Python :How to get the position number of the token in a cell dataframe that seperate by symbol (|)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

```
Car        Code          DOMAINS_616
Proton     CFC_HIC_U1    PRA_U1|PRD_U1|CFC_HIC_U1|CFC_HPC_U1|CFC_HIC_U1
Perudua    CFC_HVC_U1    PRA_U1|PRD_U1|CFC_HVC_U1|CFC_HPC_U1|CFC_HIC_U1
Toyota     CFC_HIC_U1    PRA_D1|PRD_D1|CFC_HKC_U1|CFC_HPC_U1|CFC_HOC_U1
Proton     CFC_HPC_U1    PRE_U1|PRD_U1|CFC_HPC_U1|CFC_HPC_U1|CFC_HOC_U1
```

Based on the code column I wish to know the position number at DOMAINS_616 which will seperate by | , expected output as below:

```
Car        Code          DOMAINS_616                                       Position
Proton     CFC_HIC_U1    PRA_U1|PRD_U1|CFC_HIC_U1|CFC_HPC_U1|CFC_HIC_U2    3
Perudua    CFC_HVC_U1    PRA_U1|PRD_U1|CFC_HVC_U1|CFC_HPC_U1|CFC_HIC_U1    3
Toyota     CFC_HIC_U1    PRA_D1|PRD_D1|CFC_HKC_U1|CFC_HPC_U1|CFC_HIC_U1    5   
Proton     CFC_HPC_U1    PRE_U1|PRD_U1|CFC_HLC_U1|CFC_HPC_U1|CFC_HOC_U1    4
```

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: You can just use a loop: [`[domain.split('|').index(code) + 1  for code, domain in zip(df.Code, df.DOMAINS_616)]`](https://akuiper.com/console/PNqgCtp8eTOL)

Answer (score 1):

if `Code` appears **once and only once** in `DOMAINS_616`,

first we split `DOMAINS_616` into a list and explode it

```
step1 = df.assign(dummy=df['DOMAINS_616'].apply(lambda x: list(enumerate(x.split('|'), 1)))).explode('dummy')
```

then we expand the `dummy` column into the `Position` and `domain` column

```
step1[['Position', 'domain']] = step1['dummy'].apply(pd.Series)
```

finally keep rows where `Code` matches with `domain`

```
step1[step1['Code']==step1['domain']].drop(columns=['dummy', 'domain'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`df['Position'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['DOMAINS_616'].split(|).index(row['Code'])+1, axis = 1)`